# Get all the ID of the files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm working on a folder per grade level with the same content. I used the IMPORT RANGE function to connect the spreadsheets. So I need to update the IDs every time I create another grade level. May I ask if it is possible for me to get all the IDs of all the files that I'm working on without editing or typing them one by one? Maybe a script that can make it easier?

Here's the picture of the list of IDs.

[image: IDs]

If it is possible, the flow I’m thinking of is to get the filename of the files and then get the id of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The following script will get all the file names in the range `B3:B`. Then [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) file name we use [getFilesByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename) to get the files corresponding to that name. Make sure you don't have files with the same name, otherwise this process will return multiple IDs for the same name and therefore the logic won't work.
- Finally we use [getId](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getid) to get the ID of each file and store it into an array. This array will be then pasted to column C starting from cell `C3` as you indicate in the screenshot.

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // change that to the name of your sheet
  const filenames = sh.getRange('B3:B').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!='');
  const IDs = [];
  const folderId = "put your folder id here";
  const Folder=DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  filenames.forEach(fn=>{
      let Files = Folder.getFilesByName(fn);
      while(Files.hasNext()){
          let file = Files.next();
          IDs.push([file.getId()]);
      }
  });
  sh.getRange(3,3,IDs.length,1).setValues(IDs);
}
```

Comment: There is an errror that says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null (line 8, file "Code")`. This is the link 8 `const filenames = sh.getRange('B3:B').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!='');`

Comment: @cjvdg what is the name of the sheet you want to apply this function to? As you can see in my code I use `Sheet1`. Replace that with the name of **your** sheet.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I forgot. It works now. But it gets all the IDs on my drive. I do have multiple folder with the same files per grade level. So folders with the same content and files with the same filename. Is it possible to get the ID per folder?

Comment: You need to put them in the same folder and then look in that particular folder. @cjvdg or create a folder column to indicate to which folder you want to search each file. Either way, you need to be more specific.

Comment: The folder is organized per grade level. If I'm not mistaken, I need to add codes for it to only search in a specific folder, right?

Comment: You have two options. You can find files by name but if multiple files have the same name you will get multiple IDs so you need to make sure that the names are unique. The other option is to store the files you want to get the ID into a particular folder and search them in that folder. In that case let me know and I will modify the code. @cjvdg

Comment: I think I prefer the second option in which is to get the ID into a particular folder.

Comment: @cjvdg I updated the code. Let me know if it worked for you. Don't forget to put the folder id in the variable `folderId`.

Comment: Error says `ReferenceError: getFolderById is not defined (line 11, file "Code")`. This is the line `const Folder=getFolderById(folderId);`