# Get the IDs of the files in different folders

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a follow-up question for this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64924925/google-sheets-get-all-the-id-of-the-files).

Is there a way for me to get the IDs of the file in a different folder? Below is the directory of what I'm working on.

[image: directory]

And this is the code that I'm using.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  var SSID =  ss.getId(); //sheet id
  var spreadsheetFile =  DriveApp.getFileById(SSID);
  var folderId = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();
  
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4'); // change that to the name of your sheet
  const filenames = sh.getRange('B3:B').getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!='');
  const IDs = [];
  const Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  filenames.forEach(fn=>{
      let Files = Folder.getFilesByName(fn);
      while(Files.hasNext()){
          let file = Files.next();
          IDs.push([file.getId()]);
      }
  });
  sh.getRange(3,3,IDs.length,1).setValues(IDs);
}
```

This code works fine if the files are located in a folder, but it doesn't work for subfolders or a different folder.

Below is the sheet that I'm working on.

[image: SHEET]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve the file list of all files in `folderId`.
2. Create an array for putting values to Spreadsheet.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
const IDs = [];
const Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

filenames.forEach(fn=>{
    let Files = Folder.getFilesByName(fn);
    while(Files.hasNext()){
        let file = Files.next();
        IDs.push([file.getId()]);
    }
});
```

To:

```
const Folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);

// 1. Retrieve the file list of all files in `folderId`.
const getFileList = (f, folders = [], fileList = {}) => {
  const fs = f.getFiles();
  while (fs.hasNext()) {
    const file = fs.next()
    fileList[file.getName()] = file.getId();
  }
  const fols = f.getFolders();
  const folderObjs = [];
  while (fols.hasNext()) folderObjs.push(fols.next());
  if (folderObjs.length > 0) {
    folders.push(folderObjs);
    folderObjs.forEach(fol => getFileList(fol, folders, fileList));
  }
  return fileList;
};
const fileList = getFileList(Folder);

// 2. Create an array for putting values to Spreadsheet.
const IDs = filenames.map(fn => [fileList[fn] || ""]);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that the same file names are not existing in the column "B" of the Spreadsheet. Please be careful this.

Comment: Only the ID of the sheet where the code is located is showing. Other IDs don't show.

Comment: The `folderId` is the ID of the database folder. The database folder only consists of one file. A file where all the IDs are saved. Maybe that's why only the `DB_LINK` ID is the one that is showing.

Comment: It worked when I change the value of the `folderID` to the parent folder ID. But I'm having a problem with the placing of values since it doesn't generate on the exact row the same as the file name. Maybe I'll ask it as another question. But anyway, thank you.

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. About the new issue, I noticed your new question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64940043/7108653 . So I answered it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: But is there a way for me to not input or declare the folder ID in the code? More likely it will automatically get it there.

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new question was resolved. About `But is there a way for me to not input or declare the folder ID in the code? More likely it will automatically get it there.`, unfortunately, I cannot understand it. Can I ask you about the detail of your new goal?I apologize for this.

Comment: `var folderId = "1vn5n00iCpKUWe_JsTFAesQsSmBsXu36i";` I used this code for it to work. Is there a way for it for me to not change the `folderId`? Let say that I don't want to modify it every time I'm going to duplicate the whole folder. Is there a way for it to automatically declare the `folderId`?

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, about your replying of your new question, I cannot still understand. I deeply apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So when I could understand about your new question, I would like to think of the solution. Can you give me a time to do? I deeply apologize that although I could resolve your this question, I cannot resolve your new question soon. I think that I have to study more and more.

Comment: This is also for my poor English skill, I'm sorry. I changed this code `var folderId = spreadsheetFile.getParents().next().getId();` to this code `var folderId = "1vn5n00iCpKUWe_JsTFAesQsSmBsXu36i";` for your solution to work. The problem is I don't want to change the this `folderId ` `1vn5n00iCpKUWe_JsTFAesQsSmBsXu36i` manually. Should I just ask another question for this?

Comment: @cjvdg Thank you for the additional information. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `The problem is I don't want to change the this folderId  1vn5n00iCpKUWe_JsTFAesQsSmBsXu36i manually.`. For example, can I ask you about your current goal? From it, I would like to try to understand about your new question. If I couldn't understand about it from your next replying, I apologize and I would like to recommend to post it as new question. Can you give me one more chance for understanding your new question? I apologize for my poor skill again.

Comment: Alright. I just ask another question. Will explain it there. Thank you so much Tanaike!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here. First there is the [`DriveApp.getFoldersByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfoldersbynamename) method which will return the list of all folders in your drive which match the given name You will of course need to know the name of the folder before runtime and you cannot have any other folders with the same name, or you risk taking the id of the wrong folder.

If you know the id of some folder higher up the folder tree (such as the scripts direct parent as seen in the example above, see [`File.getParents()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getparents)) you can limit the impact of the above method by using [`Folder.getFoldersByName(name)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFoldersByName(String)). The same restrictions as above apply here, but will be faster (less files to iterate over), but requires you to have the id of a parent folder.

You could also simply copy the folder id from the url if you know which file to access and will remain constant across script executions, and store it as a constant variable. This method is of course more rigid as you'll need to construct the file prior to runtime; however, you will not need to iterate overt he directory tree and will therefore be faster.

Comment: I'll try this. Thank you for this.